# Obtain Hours only from Datetime Rfacebook package

Tags: r, datetime, analysis

I am using `Rfacebook` package with `R`.
After I obtain the data from a page, I would like to do analysis about the Time Frame and `Rfacebook` successfully did the job well.
However, the column `created_time` combine the Date and Time together,

Here is the example

`2016-04-03T09:36:22+0000`

Using this function,

`dateformat <- function(datestring) { 
   date <- as.POSIXct(datestring, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000", tz = "GMT")
}`

The date turn into this

`2016-04-03 09:36:22`

The aim for my analysis is only to get the hours only `09:36` in order to plot what time are the best to see activities based on the sets of hours captured by `RFacebook` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add one line to your code. Here is the complete code:

```
dateformat <- function(datestring) { 
  date <- as.POSIXct(datestring, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000", tz = "GMT")
}

datestring <- "2016-04-03T09:36:22+0000"

result <- dateformat(datestring = datestring)

time <- format(result, "%H:%M")
[1] "09:36"
```

I hope this helps. The time is now a character.